# Leaking memory when not freeing internal cells?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, memory-leaks, try-catch

My professor wrote the following code:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator=(const Set<T>& set) {
  if (this == &set) return *this;
  T* data_temp = new T[set.size];
  try {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      temp_data[i] = set.data[i];
    }
  } catch (...) {
    delete[] temp_data;
    throw;
  }
  delete[] data;
  data = temp_data;
  size = maxSize = set.size;
  return *this;
}
```

And he pointed that `temp_data[i] = set.data[I];` calls `operator=`, and I am wondering why this doesn't leak memory?

For example if `operator=` failed in the 4th loop then we are deleting `temp_data`, but what about the values of the first 3 cells in `temp_data` which were allocated inside `operator=` code? we aren't freeing them.

Comment: `data_temp` vs `temp_data`, is this a typo?

Comment: There's no memory leak in the code above. Which operator= are you concerned about? `Set<T>::operator=` or `T::operator=`

Comment: The code above makes one allocation and one deallocation. Therefore it does not have a memory leak. Any other memory that might be allocated in other code is the responsibility of that other code. Provided the other code has also been written correctly there is no memory leak.

Comment: @John But in T::operator= we are allocating memory...

Comment: @Josh989 No we aren't. What makes you say that?

Comment: @John inside T::operator= we are allocating memory which is stored inside the cells and we aren't freeing them...

Comment: There most likely is a destructor for the class and the rule of  3/ 5 / 0 applies: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @Josh989 If (and I mean if) `T::operator=` is allocating memory, then it is the responsibility of `T::~T` to free that memory, which it will.

Comment: All the array elements were allocated with `new T[set.size]`. Assigning to an array element does not allocate memory for that element – you can only assign to objects that already exist.

Comment: @Josh989 Obviously if the `T` class leaks memory then there's a memory leak, but that's not the fault of this code. This code does not leak memory, and it's not the job of this code to fix any possible memory leaks in other code.

Comment: @Josh989 I'm still puzzled by your claim that 'in T::operator= we are allocating memory'. We don't know what `T` is. It could be anything, it could be an `int` or a `double`. `operator=` for `int` and `double` does not allocate any memory. But as I said leave `T` stuff to the `T` class, this code is correct, it frees all the memory it allocates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets remove some complications from this code. Lets assume `T == int` and instead of storing many `int`s we only store one:

```
int_store& int_store::operator=(const int_store& set)
{
    int* temp_data = new int;   (1) allocate
    try 
    {
        *temp_data = *set.data;   (2) assign
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        delete temp_data;       (3) free temp
        throw;
    }
    delete data;                (4) free old 
    data = temp_data;
}
```

The method has one allocation `int* temp_data = new int` (1). It the tries to assign the other `set`s data to that temp value (2). When this fails the `temp` has to be deleted (3) otherwise we can replace the old `data` with the new data stored in `temp_data` and before doing that we have to delete the old data (4).

There is no allocation in the `try` block. All memory allocated in the function is either deleted (when assignment fails) or it is used to replace the old data, in which case the old `data` is deleted before.

If `data` is an array instead of a single `int` (almost) nothing changes and there is no leak. The elements you worry about are already allocated in the line `T* data_temp = new T[set.size];` and then `delete[] temp_data;` will delete all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> For example if `operator=` failed in the 4th loop then we are deleting `temp_data`, but what about the values of the first 3 cells in `temp_data` which were allocated inside `operator=` code? we aren't freeing them.

`new[]` allocates the entire array and constructs *all* of the `T` objects in it, before the loop is reached. `delete[]` destructs *all* of the objects in the array, and deallocates the entire array.  So, it is the responsibility of `T`'s constructor and destructor to initialize and finalize `T`'s data members properly.

The loop merely *updates the content* of the data members of the objects in the array. It is the responsibility of `T::operator=` to copy and free `T`'s data members properly as needed.

There is no leak in this `Set::operator=` code. However there is a minor mistake - the loop needs to use `set.size` instead of `size`.

`for (int i = 0; i < set.size; ++i)`

The new array is allocated to `set.size` number of elements, so that is how many elements the loop needs to copy.

Using `size` for the loop, if the `Set` being assigned to is smaller than the `Set` being copied, the new array won't copy all of the elements. And if assigning to a `Set` that is larger, the loop will go out of bounds of both arrays.

If you are experiencing a leak, it would have to be in either `T::operator=` or in `T::~T()`, neither of which you have shown. Assuming `Set::Set()` and `Set::~Set()` are initializing and freeing `data` properly, this is.

Comment: However there is a minor mistake - the loop needs to use set.size instead of size. But they are the same

Comment: @Josh989 no, they are not the same. Think of what happens when assigning a `Set` containing 5 elements to a `Set` containing 10 elements. In the loop, `size` will still be 10 and `set.size` will be 5, so the loop with go out of bounds trying to copy 10 elements from a 5-element array into another 5-element array.